# Spring Boot MongoDB Connectivity Issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2

My Spring Boot application is trying to connect to MongoDB Database. The configuration is added on application.yml file. The application was working completely fine locally till yesterday.

But when today I am running it locally on localhost, the following error I am receiving:

```
2020-12-03 14:59:03.763[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10692[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.cluster              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server edugyanamcluster-shard-00-00.l4au7.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:551) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:433) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:273) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:257) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:254) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(SSLExtensions.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(CertificateRequest.java:818) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(CertificateRequest.java:922) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1180) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1091) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:998) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:430) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted

[2m2020-12-03 14:59:05.112[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10692[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2020-12-03 14:59:07.468[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10692[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mpertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2ControllerWebMvc#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
[2m2020-12-03 14:59:07.822[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10692[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m
```

Need advice on what is the issue all about? As the code was working completely fine few hours before.

Comment: We're starting to see the exact same issue today. Are yours from Atlas?

Comment: Yes, this issue is coming from today itself. MongoDB has updated their server actually, might have updated their cipher. The solution is actually change the TLS Version to 1.2 in JVM params. You can add in Eclipse -> Project -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM Arguments 
(add -> -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MongoDB has updated their server actually, might have updated their cipher.
The solution is actually change the **TLS Version** to **1.2** in **JVM params**.

One can add in **Eclipse** (if using it as an IDE) ->
Project -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM Arguments, add ->

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 14):

I could fix this issue using the solution from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790118/java-kubernetes-client-sslhandshakeexception-extension-5-should-not-be-present). I changed the TLS version to 1.2 in JVM params:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Thanks. Where can I add the JVM params? Can you pls guide?

Comment: If you could clarify how you would add this option to a Maven pom.xml, I'd be really grateful!

Comment: It's just an execution parameter: java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar app.jar

Comment: Thanks for saving a crisis you should be paid for this, wondering how easy it is for Mongo folks to break things as per their convenience

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. Is there any info on what caused this bug and until when we have to use this workaround?

Answer (score 5):

Other than downgrading to TLSV1.2, Upgrading your JDK fixes this too.

For JDK version 11.0.0 - 11.0.6, upgrading your JDK to a patched version.
[JDK-8236039](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236039)

JDK version 13.0.0 - 13.0.02, upgrading to 13.0.03 should resolve this issue
[JDK-8241515](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241515)

Comment: updating from 14.0.1 to 14.0.2 has also worked for me

Comment: I'm running Amazon Corretto JDK version 11.0.9.1+12-LTS and still seeing this error.

Comment: Version 15 showing the same error, but only for some of our developers. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I had literally tried everything like upgrading the jdk and all but the best solution and also the working one is changing the TLS version.

Right click on the project in IDE
Run As -> Run Configurations...
And goto Arguments tab
and in VM Arguments add this
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2

Run the application now and it should work fine.

You can refer for images attached for more clarity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2POk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAtoo.png)

Answer (score 1):

I updated from JDK 11.0.7 to 11.0.10 and now it works

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved first adding this parameter to the JVM:

-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2

But later, I changed the openjdk:12 docker image to the latest openjdk:11 (LTS) and it solved the issue without the -D parameter anymore =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236039 and I change my JDK to JDK-15 zulu: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-15-mts and it fixed the problem, I was previously using a version of Open JDK.