# Issue while connecting Mongo Atlas with Spring boot (I tried all stackoverflow solutions already)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, mongodb-atlas

I created a test DB in Mongo Atlas.

Below is the uri that I am using in the application properties of the spring boot project.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://user:pwd@cluster.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true
```

I tried this one as well.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://user:pwd@cluster.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

1. I have whitelisted my IP in the Atlas
2. My password contains only the alphanumeric character, no special character.

Still, I get the below exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 
30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.Mongo$4@707865bd. Client 
view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=cluster1-shard-00- 
01.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception= 
{com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by 
{javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in 
certificate_request}}, {address=cluster1-shard-00-02.mongodb.net:27017, 
type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: 
Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension 
(5) should not be presented in certificate_request}}, {address=cluster1-shard-00- 
00.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception= 
{com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by 
{javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in 
certificate_request}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out 
after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.Mongo$4@707865bd. 
Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=cluster1-shard-00- 
01.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception= 
{com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by 
{javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in 
certificate_request}}, {address=cluster1-shard-00-02.mongodb.net:27017, 
type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: 
Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) 
should not be presented in certificate_request}}, {address=cluster1-shard-00- 
00.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception= 
{com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by 
{javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in 
certificate_request}}]
```

Comment: Did you try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61143833/2282634

Comment: @Joe I tried now, didn't help